# Drupal: How to remove login to make site passwordless for users?

Tags: drupal, authentication

I want to remove the login page from a Drupal site so that the site is open and public-facing.  Only the admin would need to login.  Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: You want to remove the entire login page? Or just box with login and password?

Comment: As long as users can access the site without having to register and enter a password either option is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove the login page, because the administrators will need one to login.

You could, however, give anonymous users access to *whatever you like*. So that you don't have to be logged in the use any feature of the site. If users are to create content or do other stuff, you will need for them to login, so that you can tell them apart.

**Edit**
To configure the access control, you'll have to go to `admin/user/permissions`, where you can select which permissions anonymous users (and other user roles) should have.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to do.  How can I give anonymous users access to a page/part of the site?

Comment: Just figured it out before reading your reply, thank you though - you pointed me in the right direction - seems obvious in hindsight!

Answer (score 0):

I looked through permissions, but nothing helped me to make the main site page available instead of the login page.

Open Features (site.org/features), change Site settings -> Site work mode from Only private access to Open access (moderated registration) (sorry, the names were translated back from Russian).

This has solved my problem. I made private access to the site before and forgot about that. I wanted to disable new users registration (because of mass spam). This can be done through admin/user/settings -> Only site administrators can create new user accounts. [I use Drupal 6, but Drupal 7 works same with this setting]. [UPDATE: it seems, at least for my somewhat outdated setup, that these two Drupal options contradict each other, when I allow only administrators to add users, the private mode turns on automatically :( ]

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7

You do not need to remove the login page to make the site open and public facing. Any browser to your site would be given an anonymous user role by default. So any content that is visible to the anonymous role (which can be altered by going to admin/user/permissions) and published can be seen. As long as your website is not in maintenance mode.

If your looking to move the login block that is on the front page of most new Drupal installations you'll have to go to admin/structure/blocks and change the setting there.